# Has URL Fetch limits (quotas) in Google Data Studio Community Connectors?

Tags: urlfetch, looker-studio

I'm talking about "URL Fetch calls" and "URL Fetch data received" in
in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community Connectors are created in Apps Scripts and [all Apps Scripts quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) apply to them. This is the quota for your connector communicating to the data source and does not affect the communication between the connector and Data Studio.

Comment: Hi! Does the quota apply to a script per day or per user and script? After all, if I have many users, then the quota will quickly end.

Comment: Per user per day.